# trouble with slick 2d unicode font

Tags: java, opengl, rendering, lwjgl

ok so I have determined that if I change my orthographic matrix coordinate system to

`GL11.glOrtho(0, Strings.DISPLAY_WIDTH, Strings.DISPLAY_HEIGHT, 0, -1, 1);`

instead of this

`GL11.glOrtho(0, Strings.DISPLAY_WIDTH, 0, Strings.DISPLAY_HEIGHT, -1, 1);`

I can draw strings with slick right side up however the game im building uses this system

```
GL11.glOrtho(0, Strings.DISPLAY_WIDTH, 0, Strings.DISPLAY_HEIGHT, -1, 1);
```

and slick draws things with the top of the matrix being 0 and the bottom being the height of the display is there anyway I can rotate or draw the strings differently without having to change my games coordinate system?

here is my string drawing class

```
private Font javaFont;
private UnicodeFont uniFont;

public TextHandler(int letterSize) {
    this.initHandler(letterSize);
}

private void initHandler(int size) {
    this.javaFont = new Font("Times New Roman", Font.BOLD, size);
    this.uniFont = new UnicodeFont(this.javaFont);

    this.uniFont.getEffects().add(new ColorEffect(java.awt.Color.white));

    this.uniFont.addAsciiGlyphs();

    try {
        this.uniFont.loadGlyphs();
    } catch (SlickException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public void drawString(String string, float x, float y) {
    this.uniFont.drawString(x, y, string, Color.white);
}
```

and my openGl initialization code if it helps

```
    GL11.glMatrixMode(GL11.GL_PROJECTION);
    GL11.glLoadIdentity();
    GL11.glOrtho(0, Strings.DISPLAY_WIDTH, 0, Strings.DISPLAY_HEIGHT, -1, 1);

    GL11.glMatrixMode(GL11.GL_MODELVIEW);
    GL11.glEnable(GL11.GL_TEXTURE_2D);
    GL11.glClearColor(0, 0, 1, 0);
    GL11.glDisable(GL11.GL_DEPTH_TEST);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you could set up a rendering system where the first `glOrtho` call sets up the Slick rendering, and then you render the strings. Then you call `glOrtho` again, but render the rest of your game. `glOrtho` simply tells OpenGL to setup an orthographic projection, and what corner of the screen to start rendering from. Slick uses the top left hand corner whereas you are using the bottom left hand corner. OpenGL is a state based machine, so you must render the Slick stuff, switch to the new projection, and then render the rest of your game.

You also don't need that call to `glDisable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);`. Depth testing is turned off by default.